# Cannot Insert into Extended VARCHAR2 using JDBCTemplate

Tags: java, oracle

The need arose to store in excess of 4000 bytes into VARCHAR2 in Oracle database. The workaround was to engage the 'Extended Data Types'on the database to increase capacity. I am storing a maximum of 2000 characters but the special characters I'm inserting are up to 3 bytes each.

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF55623

Manual insertion using SQLDeveloper or a SQL statement **works fine**. Tested with 2000 characters / 6000 bytes.

However, when attempting to insert any String over 4000 bytes using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, I receive the following error:

**Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column**

This leads me to believe that it is a driver issue of some type. I'm using dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>10.3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code:

```
@Override
public Number createRecord(Number incidentId, String type, 
String verbatim, String createdBy) {
     MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
     parameters.addValue(MyConstants.MAP_VERBATIM, verbatim);
     namedTemplate.update(insertRecordSql, parameters, key, new 
     String[]{"VERBATIM_ID"});
     return key.getKey();
}
```

Column definition:

"VERBATIM" VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your maven entry looks strange. You are trying to utilize `oracle 12c` enhancement but still, you are using jar from oracle 10 `<version>10.3.6.0</version>` . Moreover if you jdk is higher than jdk6 you probably you have to use ojdbc7

Comment: This was the problem. Changing to 12.1.3 fixed it.